# Does DecorView hold the Status Bar?

Tags: android, statusbar

Does DecorView hold the Status Bar?
When I dump View Hierarchy for UI automator with Eclise ADT's DDMS, I find that a View holds two FrameLayouts.
As shown on the image, the DecorView seems to be holding the statusbar, but where is the status bar's layout?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If by Status Bar you mean the part that displays WiFi connection, battery level etc. then this part is drawn by a different process on Android (System UI process). Your apps content is drawn underneath the status bar. The same thing applies to the navigation bar at the bottom.